# How to connect to Azure IoT hub using cordova plugin and java script?

Tags: javascript, azure, cordova-plugins, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-sdk

Any cordova plugin that connects to azure iot hub and methods to upload files?

Comment: Is there any reason why you are not using one of our open sourced Azure IoT SDKs? See the Benefits of using the Azure IoT SDKs: https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdks, and pitfalls to avoid if you don’t:https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/benefits-of-using-the-azure-iot-sdks-in-your-azure-iot-solution/

I haven't found a plugin. You may check this https://www.microsoft.com/developerblog/2016/08/31/cordova-iot-simulator/ and see if it helps.

Comment: No cordova plugin present for azure iot sdk. SDK's are present only for Java, C, Node, phython and .net. How can i write a hybrid app that works both for iOS and Android devices.

Comment: @AshokPeddakotla-MSFT No cordova wrapper is available for android and ios Azure iot sdk's.

Comment: Please provide your feedback on the Uservoice forum: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/321918-azure-iot and upvote it for this feature.